# Why does Angular append 'Provider' to my service name?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out why Angular is giving me the following error on a provider I have not declared anywhere.

> Error: $injector:unpr
>      Unknown provider: dblServiceProvider <-

Here's the skeleton of my factory:

```
angular.module('fv.services', [])
.factory('dblService', function($q, $http) {
    this.getAll = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var responsePromise = $http.post(URL, POSTPARAMS)
        .success( function(data, status, header, config) {
            // do something
        })

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        getAll: getAll()
    };
});
```

I try to instantiate that service in a controller, and this is where the error above is triggered.

```
.controller('searchCtrl', ['lotsOfInjections', 'dblService', function(lotsOfInjections, dblService) {
    // do something
}]);
```

Why does Angular append "Provider" and look for a provider I haven't declared?

Comment: the error means it can find your factory with the name that precedes `'Provider'`

Comment: FYI, `'$q'` and `'$http'` are **not** modules so should be removed from your `fv.services` module's dependency array

Comment: You're also missing a comma after `'lotsOfInjections'`

Comment: thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because all services are created by a provider, and the provider of a service is always the service name followed by "Provider".

When you define a service `foo` using a factory, Angular in fact creates a provider `fooProvider`, that delegates to the factory to create the service instance. This provider is stored in the registry of service providers. When another component needs the service `foo`, angular looks for `fooProvider` in its registry.